How to get typescript to be more specific in string interpolation over a union
export const schedules = [
    { unit: "hour", quantity: 6 },
    { unit: "day", quantity: 1 },
] as const;

const getScheduleName = (schedule: (typeof schedules)[number]) =>
    `${schedule.quantity}_${schedule.unit}` as const


type Schedule<
    T extends (typeof schedules)[number] = (typeof schedules)[number],
> = `${T["quantity"]}_${T["unit"]}`

Why are the Schedule type and the return type of getScheduleName "6_hour" | "6_day" | "1_hour" | "1_day" instead of "6_hour" | "1_day"?
Is there any way to make typescript more specific in this case?

This is ms/TS#49132 and ms/TS#30581. Just because (typeof schedules)[number] is a discriminated union, it doesn't mean that TS can maintain the correlation at the type level. The only way to have TS do this by itself is to make the function generic. Furthermore, if schedule is generic, then schedule.quantity will end up not being generic because TS tends to widen generics to their constraints. (more...)

(...continued)  So you'd need a helper to prevent that. Finally, you need as const to tell TS to interpret the template literal as a template literal type. Putting these together gives you the code in this playground link. Does that meet fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yes i have the as const i just forgot it in the example above, and this didn't work with a generic either, i tried that as i don't really need the function it was just one of my iterations to get the type right

"i don't really need the function" ?? I'm confused. Given your question as written, my suggestion would still be to use the code in this playground link.  You say it "didn't work with a generic either" but you haven't shown the failure.  What specifically is the problem? Could you please [edit] to show a use case where my suggested approach fails? Then we can proceed.

@jcalz I only need the type of the union of possible combinations, i don't need the function.
I added a code block of the generic i was using before, it has the same issue as the return type of the function.
I initially started with the generic, then tried to make it work, and when it wouldn't i tried the function to extract its return type
When i try to extract the return type of the function in your playground link, it returns any, so it wouldn't work for my use case

I'm asking you to [edit] to show with code where the issue is, otherwise we're just describing the code and the chance for miscommunication is high. Right now I can't tell if you're just looking to describe the type, or you're trying to write code that will look at the template literal string value and give it the appropriate union. If it's the former, we can do that. If it's the latter, generics are still the only approach to do it "safely", as per ms/TS#47109, which looks like this playground link.

(see prev comment) I'll disengage for now.  If you make the requisite [edit] to clarify the question with a [mre] that demonstrates the failed use case, I'll revisit. Good luck!

I'm sorry i don't completely follow, i thought my code and intentions were clear, both the code blocks provided perfectly reproduce the issue described, they result in the type "6_hour" | "6_day" | "1_hour" | "1_day" instead of the following desired type "6_hour" | "1_day"
My goal is to take the schedules array and produce the type of the possible values  with the following pattern "6_hour" | "1_day" from it dynamically

It seems we are having a communication problem and I'm not sure how to fix it. I'll try one more time. Do you just care about the type? If so then you need to actually iterate or distribute over the members of your union; it doesn't happen automatically. That looks like this playground link. If you care about getting TS to "understand" that \${schedule.quantity}_${schedule.unit}`` actually produces a value of that type, you'll need to jump through significantly more hoops as shown in this playground link. Which, if either, is it?

Seems like TS does not take into account discriminated unions when generating possible values for the template literal. Might be a limitation, might be just a bug, could be worth submitting an issue to the TypeScripts github page.
The workaround I can think of is to cast it to what it should be:

export const schedules = [
    { unit: "hour", quantity: 6 },
    { unit: "day", quantity: 1 },
] as const;

type Schedule = (typeof schedules)[number]

const getScheduleName = <T extends Schedule>(schedule: T) =>
    `${schedule.quantity}_${schedule.unit}` as `${T["quantity"]}_${T["unit"]}`
    
let result = getScheduleName({ unit: "hour", quantity: 6 })

Playground
Casting is not safe, you basically silencing TS compiler, so I usually try to isolate all casting to simple functions and cover them with unit tests, since someone else can come around and change the output and TS won't complain.
const getScheduleName = <T extends Schedule>(schedule: T) =>
    `${schedule.quantity} ==> ${schedule.unit}` as `${T["quantity"]}_${T["unit"]}` // no error

